# What is Spring transaction isolation level if there is no @Transactional annotation on a function

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I have two services

```
@Transactional
class updateService(User user){
  ...
  SaveEmail(User){

  }
 }
```

On updateService (see above code ) have @Transactional annotation and it will have Ioslation level "Default" i.e default transaction defined in the database.

```
class updateService2(User user){
  ...
  SaveEmail(User){
  }
 }
```

In updateService2 , we don't have @Transactional annotation.

1. Does updateService2 will have any Isolation level ?
2. Whether query in updateService2 i.e SaveEmail method will run in default transaction   Isolataion povided by the database?

Comment: there is no Transaction applied by spring if you have not marked it, hence no isolation level

Comment: Actually it depends... If you call `updateService2` from another method that doesn't have a transaction, then there is no transaction created and nothing will happen (might even throw an exception). If you are calling it from another `@Transactional` method it will participate in that ongoing transaction and inherit all its benefits. It will not start a new one or whatever unless it itself is annotated with `@Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)`.